# Jenkins "Failed to install JDK" Exit code=-1

Tags: java, jenkins

(Adding this here as I did not find an answer anywhere)

I configured Jenkins to automatically install JDK from the "Global Tools Configuration" > "JDK Installation" menu. The option works across all 14 nodes (various Windows and Linux) but one.

A server Windows Server 2012 R2 (amd64) with 20 executors, which has been running without issue for just under 3 years.

The log file references in the build's console (i.e. ...tools\hudson.model.JDK\install1873722508778839961log) is empty.

The build's console shows the following:

> [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables. Installing
>   E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Oracle_Java_8.0_191\jdk.exe
>   [Oracle_Java_8.0_191] $
>   E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Oracle_Java_8.0_191\jdk.exe
>   /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   INSTALLDIR=E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Oracle_Java_8.0_191
>   /L
>   E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\install1873722508778839961log
>   Failed to install JDK. Exit code=-1 ERROR: SEVERE ERROR occurs
>   org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: hudson.AbortException
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.util.RunHelper.getBuildVariables(RunHelper.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectListener.setUpEnvironmentWithoutJobPropertyObject(EnvInjectListener.java:235)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectListener.setUpEnvironment(EnvInjectListener.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.createLauncher(AbstractBuild.java:542)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:462)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)  at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)    at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) Caused by:
>   hudson.AbortException     at
>   hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.install(JDKInstaller.java:292)  at
>   hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:157)
>     at
>   hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
>     at
>   hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
>     at
>   hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
>     at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:148)   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.util.RunHelper.getJDKVariables(RunHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.util.RunHelper.getBuildVariables(RunHelper.java:135)
>     ... 8 more

Answer (score 0):

I logged onto the server as a local admin and attempted to run the JDK installation line shown in the build console:

> E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Oracle_Java_8.0_191\jdk.exe
>   /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   INSTALLDIR=E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK\Oracle_Java_8.0_191
>   /L E:\Jenkins_APA_8080\tools\hudson.model.JDK

The installation seemed to run and this time the log file contained text. I double checked the owner and permissions on the Jenkins folders and they were owned by a local admin and not a domain admin (this is normal for our Jenkins installation).

However, the login credentials of the Jenkins service on this machine were set to a domain admin (not local admin).

Changing the Jenkins Services Log On credentials resolved the issue. Even though this node has been running for over a couple years without issue, its credentials were not correct.